# SQL: how to map two columns from tables with distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query as below which fetches count of `id` column for 1 month period of time.

```
   select distinct id, count(1) from table_1 where START_TIME 
    between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1))
    group by id;
```

But id need to be mapped with some other column from other table named `table_2` with columns as `id`,`name`.

I have tried doing some like below

```
select distinct t1.id, t1.count(1),t2.name from table_1 t1, table_2 t2 where START_TIME 
        between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) and t1.id = t2.id
        group by t1.id ;
```

But I end up SQL syntax errors.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: `t1.count(1)` is nonsensical. Do `COUNT(t1.id)`. Also, please do some explicit joins, it's easier to debug this way. Also, if START_TIME is a column in t1, you need to do `t1.START_TIME` instead.

Comment: You can try `not in` [Link](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-not-in.htm)

Comment: @Magisch Why do you think `t1.count(1)` is nonsensical and `COUNT(t1.id).`  is making sense.

Comment: @XING I assume he wants to count the occurences of the duplicates he filters out. COUNT(t1.id) is better for that.

Comment: @Magisch Unfortunately you need to understand that there is no difference using `Count(1)/count(*) and count(anythig)` . Please read Oracle docs for more clarification. Also issue is with `group by` clause. And if you downvote my answer you should have explaination for doing it was well. Thats called positive critisim.

Comment: @XING with the group by and with the START_TIME as well as (not breaking but still bad) the fact that it's not an explicit join, imo.

Comment: @Magisch, i tried your suggestion as well and its working fine. Thank you.

Comment: @XING: there **is** a difference between `count(*)` and `count(some_column)` if `some_colum` is nullable. But it's true that there is **no** difference whatsoever between `count(*)` and `count(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this: You need to include all the columns in `Select` in `group by` clause as well.

```
 SELECT t1.id, COUNT (1), t2.name
    FROM table_1 t1 INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
   WHERE     t1.START_TIME BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1)
                               AND LAST_DAY (
                                      ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1))
         AND t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.name;
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting error as "COUNT" invalid identifier ? Any idea ?

Comment: @Ten-Coin try it now

Comment: I tried with count(t1.id) and it working good, @RadimBača ok trying XING answer now.

Comment: What is the reason of having t1.id = t2.id in the where clause? And using count(1) is a bit nonsensical. We are not counting literals, we are counting rows. Count(1) is blast from the past - when it was thought that it worked faster then count(*).